# How to split values in a column after using groupby in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have used the following code to display top 3 products of each retailer

```
baseline_df = baseline_df.groupby(['RtrName'])['Product'].agg(lambda x:x.value_counts().index[0:3]).to_frame().reset_index()
```

The result of this is a dataframe with two columns - RtrName and Product but each row in the Product column has 3 values split by a comma (,)

Result Output:

```
RtrName  Product
RtrName_a Product1,Product2,Product3
RtrName_b Product1,Product2,Product3
```

I want to have my dataframe in a way like : Expected Output

```
RtrName_a  Product1
           Product2
           Product3 
RtrName_b  Product1
           Product2
           Product3
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) of splitted values by [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) before your solution:

```
baseline_df = (baseline_df.assign(Product = baseline_df.Product.str.split(','))
                          .explode('Product')
                          .groupby(['RtrName'])['Product']
                          .agg(lambda x:x.value_counts().index[:3])
                          .reset_index(name='new'))
```

Different output is if use `explode` after `groupby`:

```
baseline_df = (baseline_df.groupby(['RtrName'])['Product']
                          .agg(lambda x:x.value_counts().index[:3])
                          .str.split(',')
                          .explode()
                          .reset_index(name='Product'))
```

Comment: Hi! ValueError: columns must be unique. When I tried the first code sample.

Comment: No, not happening. It says : ValueError: columns must be unique

Comment: I have edited my question. Showing the resultant output vs expected output.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried it this way and achieved what I wanted.

```
def func(x):
    x = x[:10]
    return x['Product']
    
temp = baseline_df.groupby('RtrName').apply(lambda x: func(x))
temp = temp.to_frame().reset_index().drop(columns=['level_1'])
```